# Changing a div into another text using ajax with api

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

```
<script type"text/Javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button").click(function(){
        htmlobj = $.ajax({url:"test.txt",async:false});
        $("#lyrics").html(htmlobj.responseText);
    });
});

<div id=lyrics> This text must change </div>
<button id="button">small axe</button>
```

I am trying to insert lyrics by using AJAX but it is not working and I cannot find the error.

Comment: uh... your `AJAX` call looks a bit... f'd up... are you ajaxing a txt doc on your server...?

Answer (score 0):

You trying to get response text wrong.

Use this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url:"test.txt",
            success: function(responseText) {
                $("#lyrics").html(responseText);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

You have to handle respone only in `success` event of ajax request. It is inaccessible outside of it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the load function, it is a little easier. I have fixed your markup, the id was missing quotes, and also updated the button attributes so that it can be used for more than one file.

updated html:

```
<div id="lyrics"> This text must change </div>
<button class="button" id="smallAxe">small axe</button>
```

updated js:

```
$(".button").click(function(){   
    var filename = $(this).attr('id');   
    $("#lyrics").load(filename+".txt");
});
```

This would load the contents of a file named 'smallAxe.txt' into the `div#lyrics`.

Alternatively, you could create a single html file, and call it something like 'marley.html' and have a bunch of songs in there, each song wrapped in a div with the id denoting the tile, like:

```
<div id='small_axe'>lyrics...</div>

<div id='stir_it_up'>lyrics...</div>

<div id='one_love'>lyrics...</div>

<div id='400_years'>lyrics...</div>
```

and call the lyrics from that file like so...

```
<button class="button" data-song="small_axe" data-artist="marley">small axe</button>

$(".button").click(function(){   
    var artist = $(this).data('artist');   
    var song = $(this).data('song');   
    $("#lyrics").load(artist+".html #"+song);
});
```